# A change in trend towards end 2022? Don't invest money in the stock market anymore, but leave it in a savings account?

Tags: stock-markets, interest-rate, inflation, savings-account, switzerland

Many in this community and other forums recommend S&P500 and some other index funds. After the index fund fell sharply, I also thought now is the opportunity to enter.

But now I read in the news that savings accounts get interest again. At the moment still small, but experts believe that the interest on savings accounts will rise. Also no more negative interest rates.

Is there now or very soon a change in trend?

Do I not have to do the time-consuming process of following courses, informing myself etc. at all and leave my money in the savings account?

My profits since 2017 was mimim, possibly even zero - have the overview not quite exactly because different bank institutes

Comment: Don't try to time the market. It is a losing endeavor.

Comment: In most countries, inflation will eat up any gains from increased savings interest rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the index fund fell sharply, I also thought now is the opportunity to enter.

Good thought. But S&P 500 is very US-centric. If you want to invest worldwide, e. g. a FTSE All World ETF might be better because other markets might be intersting as well.

> But now I read in the news that savings accounts get interest again. At the moment still small, but experts believe that the interest on savings accounts will rise.

This is probably true, but in the past the stock markets always had a higher return (at least if you look at time spans of decasdes) than saving accounts.

> Do I not have to do the time-consuming process of following courses, informing myself etc.

What are you talking about? If you put x00 €/$/CHF per month into an ETF and leave it until retirement (ideally), you don't have to follow courses at all.

So yes, even now it would be wise to start investing. If you don't feel comfortable, don't invest all at once, but invest a small amount of money via a savings plan.

Answer (score 3):

The stock market is an instant money weighted opinion of future returns.

It is very nicely represented as a first order auto-regressive time series (a random walk, where only the last point represents any information content, which is just a re-statement of my opening remark). As a reference, see ["which model should I use in order to represent stock market price from theoretical perspective?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92626/which-model-should-i-use-in-order-to-represent-stock-market-price-from-theoretic).

Money in the bank is very likely going to lose buying power (even after collecting the promised interest). Fixed income returns, in a likely ongoing inflationary environment, will certainly be safe but don't expect positive real returns.

Risk takers get premiums.

Answer (score -1):

**YES**, that is the wanted effect of the FED. As Jerome Powell stated earlier this month, the fed not gonna stop raising rate 'till they curl inflation and reduce the money in the circuit (ie QT).

Disclosure: I will not put money into the saving account in the mean time and continue to invest into the market.

Comment: No relation to FED - question is tagged <tag>Switzerland</tag>.